# html button is not becoming hidden on image button click

Tags: asp.net

I have a html image button and two html buttons . I want to hide both the buttons on image button click.
But whenever i am pressing an image button the page is reloaded and the buttons are visible . 
Everything works fine when i do not hide the Stop_Camera_view button.
Here is my code,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function HideStartStopButton() {
         document.getElementById("Start_Camera_view").hidden = true;
         document.getElementById("Stop_Camera_view").hidden = true;
     }    
</script>
<input id="imgBtnSequencing" type="image" src="../images/update_btn.gif" value="Sequencing" onclick="HideStartStopButton();return false;"/>
<button id="Start_Camera_view" name="Start_Camera_view" type="button" onclick="StartSequencingTimer()">Start</button>
<button name="Stop_Camera_view" type="button" onclick="StopSequencingTimer()" title="Stop all cameras">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Hi, did these answers solve your issue? If so, vote and accept one as an answer. And, vote for all the useful answers. In this way you are encouraging others to participate in SO's Q&A.

Comment: Hi, If these answers were helpful please vote and accept. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to take id of 2nd button.

Take id of 2nd button.

Replace your html code

```
<button id="Start_Camera_view" name="Start_Camera_view" type="button" onclick="StartSequencingTimer()">Start</button>
<button name="Stop_Camera_view" type="button" onclick="StopSequencingTimer()" title="Stop all cameras">Stop</button>
```

with this:

```
<button id="Start_Camera_view" name="Start_Camera_view" type="button" onclick="StartSequencingTimer()">Start</button>
<button id="Stop_Camera_view_2" type="button" onclick="StopSequencingTimer()" title="Stop all cameras">Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify your Script like this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function HideStartStopButton() {
            document.getElementById('<%= Start_Camera_view.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById('<%= Stop_Camera_view.ClientID %>').style.display = "none";
        }    
</script>
```

And, You also need to add an ID attribute to your second button like this

```
<button ID="Stop_Camera_view" type="button" onclick="StopSequencingTimer()" title="Stop all cameras">Stop</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use C# and change your buttons to asp:ImageButton and two asp:Button you can hide the buttons like this:

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="imgBtnSequencing" runat="server" ImageUrl="../images/update_btn.gif" OnClick="HideStartStopButton_Click" />

<asp:Button id="Start_Camera_view" OnClick="StartSequencingTimer_Click" runat="server" /> 

<asp:Button id="Start_Camera_view2" OnClick="StopSequencingTimer_Click" runat="server" />



 protected void imgBtnSequencing_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
          if(sender == imgBtnSequencing)
            {
                Start_Camera_view.Visible = false;
                Start_Camera_view2.Visible = false;
            }
      }
```